# How to upgrade Istio Service Mesh from http to http2?

Tags: http, kubernetes, http2, kubernetes-ingress, istio

We are on Kubernetes and use Istio Service Mesh. Currently, there is SSL Termination for HTTPS in Gateway. I see in the istio-proxy logs that the HTTP protocol is HTTP 1.1.

I want to upgrade HTTP 1.1 to HTTP2 due to its various advantages. Clients should call our services HTTP2 over SSL/TLS.

I am using this [blog](https://blog-tech.groupeonepoint.com/playing-with-istio-service-mesh-on-kubernetes/) for an internal demo on this topic.

These are the bottlenecks:

1) I want to propose a plan which will causes least amount of changes. I understand I need to update the Gateway from

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - "*"
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/certs/server.pem
      privateKey: /etc/certs/privatekey.pem
```

to

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http2
      protocol: HTTP2
    hosts:
    - "*"
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/certs/server.pem
      privateKey: /etc/certs/privatekey.pem
```

based on the examples I see in the [Istio's Gateway documentation](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/#Server).

I want to know: Will this allow HTTP2 over TLS connections from browsers (which support only this mode)? Can I provide tls details for HTTP2, like I did with HTTPS?

2) What are some of the other Istio configurations to update?

3) Will this change be break Microservices which are using http protocol currently? How can I mitigate this?

4) I was reading about DestinationRule and [upgrade policy](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ConnectionPoolSettings-HTTPSettings-H2UpgradePolicy). Is this a good fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, [istio documentation](https://istio.io/) and istio [feature stages](https://istio.io/about/feature-stages/)(http2 in stable phase)

> 1) Will this allow HTTP2 over TLS connections from browsers (which support only this mode)? Can I provide tls details for HTTP2, like I did with HTTPS?

Yes, it should allow http2.

---

> 2) What are some of the other Istio configurations to update?

Places when You have options to apply http2 :

---

- [**Gateway**](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/#Server)

---

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-ingress-gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: **http2**
      protocol: **HTTP2**
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

---

- [**Service protocol selection**](https://istio.io/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/protocol-selection/)

---

**Manual protocol selection**

> Protocols can be specified manually by naming the Service port name: [-]. The following protocols are supported:

- grpc
- grpc
- web
- http
- **http2**
- https
- mongo
- mysql*
- redis*
- tcp
- tls
- udp

> *These protocols are disabled by default to avoid accidentally enabling experimental features. To enable them, configure the corresponding Pilot environment variables.

---

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice
spec:
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: http2
```

---

> 3) Will this change be break Microservices which are using http protocol currently? How can I mitigate this?
>
> 4) I was reading about DestinationRule and upgrade policy. Is this a good fit?

I think it should be a good fit,You would have to upgrade [h2UpgradePolicy](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ConnectionPoolSettings-HTTPSettings-H2UpgradePolicy) and change services to http2.

---

I hope it will help You.

Comment: Hello. I updated the services as advised. I'm getting 503 error. Any reasons?

Comment: Hello @AnoopHallimala , So if you change gateway and destination rule everything works fine with name http in services, but if You change it to http2 it fails? As far as i checked on your another post curl everything works fine with option 1?

Comment: Yes, @jt97. Thats correct. http in services work just fine. But, the moment I change it to http2, it starts giving me 503. DestinationRules in both cases stay the same.