# Istio 1.7.2 - problem WebSocket connection

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, istio

I have problem related to WebSocket connection on - Istio Ingress Gateway 
**My cluster:**
Istio - 1.7.2, Kubernetes - 1.18.6

I’m trying to run my application on new config cluster, My app is working properly on Istio 1.5.1 and k8s 1.15.11.

I have one problem with properly WebSocket connection on internal IngressGateway, rest of features is working.

**Config:**

I using two Istio IngressGateways:

- default external IngressGateway
- internal IngressGateway (ClusterIP)

**Example traffic flow:**

Internet > external IngressGateway > Ocelot Gateway > internal IngressGateway > services (pods)

This communication is working properly for http - but websocket doesn’t working.

I found that connection is break on internal IngressGateway.

I see only this log - internal ingress gateway pod:

`[2020-10-12T10:05:16.903Z] "- - HTTP/2" 0 DPE "-" "-" 0 0 0 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 10.244.2.62:8080 10.244.1.16:58426 - -`

I don’t see any traffic in my destination service.

I have checked websocket connection directly on my destination service and there is working properly.

I have tried change VirtualService config - add „websocketUpgrade: True” - but there isn’t this field on new Istio.

Istio installation:
I have used istioctl, my IstioOperator below:

> ```
>  apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
>     kind: IstioOperator
>     spec:
>       meshConfig:
>     accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
>       components:
>     ingressGateways:
>       - namespace: istio-system
>         name: internal-ingressgateway
>         label: 
>           app: internal-ingressgateway
>           istio: internal-ingressgateway
>         enabled: true
>         k8s:
>           resources:
>             requests:
>               cpu: 100m
>               memory: 1000Mi
>           service:
>             type: ClusterIP
>             ports:
>             - port: 80
>               targetPort: 8080
>       values:
>     gateways:
>       istio-ingressgateway:
>         debug: Trace
>     global:
>       istiod:
>         enableAnalysis: true
>     pilot:
>       env:
>         PILOT_ENABLE_STATUS: true
> ```

Do you have any ideas on these issues?

**UPDATE** - add configs:

External IngressGateway

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: external-gtw
  namespace: istio-system
  labels:
    app: ingressgateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP2
      name: http
    hosts:
    - "*"
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true # sends 301 redirect for http requests
  - port:
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
      name: https-default
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: "sds"
      privateKey: "sds"
      credentialName: ........
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

Internal IngressGateway

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: internal-gtw
  namespace: istio-system
  labels:
    app: internal-gtw
spec:
  selector:
    app: internal-ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP2
      name: http
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

VirtualService

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: notificationservice
spec:
  gateways:
  - istio-system/internal-gtw
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /notificationservice/
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: notificationservice
```

DestinationRules - currently I don't use

Comment: Hi, Can you add gateways, virtualservices and destinationrules yaml manifests?

Comment: @PiotrMalec I added all configs to main post. Thanks for investigate

Comment: Hmm, it looks to me like the http2 connection upgrade fails in the new version. Can you try and change the name of your protocol in gateway / service configuration to something else than `http` as explained in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59610581/12014434)?

Comment: Any update on this @merdokss? Could you resolve it?